# issue with script container under devops azure vsts biild

Tags: azure-devops

i attempt to create a job for my java to run them in docker container

i prepare this script to execute on docker machine from vsys build :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe
docker-compose --project-name CRM-module-itg -f environnement-integration.yml down -v
docker-compose --project-name CRM-module-itg -f environnement-integration.yml up --build -d
rm -rf ~/crm_module/infrastructure/*
echo 'script executed with success !'
```

the vsts job execute  " bash -x crm_module/infrastructure/RunApp-EnvIntegration.sh"

the build show many error

```
2019-04-27T13:01:34.4046900Z ##[error]+ set -xe
2019-04-27T13:01:34.4046900Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:34.4046900Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:34.4046900Z ##[error]+ ********-compose --project-name CRM-module-itg -f /home/********/crm_module/infrastructure/environnement-integration.yml down -v
2019-04-27T13:01:34.4046900Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:34.8577997Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:34.8577997Z ##[error]Stopping CRM-module-itg ... 
2019-04-27T13:01:34.8577997Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3421658Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3421658Z ##[error][1A[2K
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3421658Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3421658Z [1B
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3421658Z ##[error]Stopping CRM-module-itg ... [32mdone[0m
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3421658Z [1B
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3577945Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3577945Z ##[error]Removing CRM-module-itg ... 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.3577945Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.4359281Z Removing CRM-module-itg ... [32mdone[0m
2019-04-27T13:01:35.4359281Z [1B
2019-04-27T13:01:35.4359281Z ##[error][1A[2K
2019-04-27T13:01:35.4359281Z Removing CRM-module-itg ... [32mdone[0m
2019-04-27T13:01:35.4359281Z [1B
2019-04-27T13:01:35.4359281Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.4359281Z ##[error]Removing network crmmoduleitg_app_net
2019-04-27T13:01:35.4359281Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.9046736Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:35.9046736Z ##[error]+ ********-compose --project-name CRM-module-itg -f /home/********/crm_module/infrastructure/environnement-integration.yml up --build -d
2019-04-27T13:01:35.9046736Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:36.4359114Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:36.4359114Z ##[error]Creating network "crmmoduleitg_app_net" with driver "bridge"
2019-04-27T13:01:36.4359114Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:36.9515615Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:36.9515615Z ##[error]Building web
```

Also

when i execute

```
dos2unix crm_module/infrastructure/RunApp-EnvIntegration.sh


2019-04-27T13:01:33.0296983Z dos2unix crm_module/infrastructure/RunApp-EnvIntegration.sh
2019-04-27T13:01:33.3421690Z ##[error]dos2unix: 
2019-04-27T13:01:33.3421690Z 
2019-04-27T13:01:33.3421690Z ##[error]converting file crm_module/infrastructure/RunApp-EnvIntegration.sh to Unix format ...
2019-04-27T13:01:33.3421690Z
```

Any idea to resolve this ?